# Is there a way to install the Ubuntu phone demo SDK on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, development, ubuntu-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the QML toolkit on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235440/how-do-i-install-the-qml-toolkit-on-12-04)

I thought "why not start with the new shown Ubuntu phone seems noob to coding friendly enough" except when installing the qt stuff it says "NOT FOUND".

I did `apt-get update` is it only possible on 12.10, I just installed Ubuntu and don't want to have to re-install.

When I run `apt-get update`, I got this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I think that has to do with the fact I'm on 12.04.